# Frequency of common elements between lists in python 2.7

Tags: list, python-2.7, duplicates, frequency

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['red','blue', 'yellow'] #unique

list2 = ['green','purple','red','yellow','purple', 'red'] #duplicates
```

I found multiple Q&A for finding the unique common elements between two lists OR the frequency of elements in a list:

```
import numpy as np

match  = np.in1d(list1,list2, assume_unique=False) 

match = list(set(list1).intersection(set(list2)))

match = set(list1) & set(list2)

[element for element in list1 if element in list2]

list2, common = list1[:], [ e for e in list1 if e in list2 and (list2.pop(list2.index(e)))]

from scipy.stats import itemfreq

count = itemfreq(res)

list.count
```

But what I need is the frequency of common elements, if any, between two lists:

```
['red', 2],['blue',0],['yellow',1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of comprehensions can do this concisely:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [3,4,5,3,3]

itemcounter = {item:count for item, count in [(item, list2.count(item)) for item in set(list1)]}
final_counts = [(item, count) for item, count in itemcounter.iteritems()]

print(final_counts)
```

...produces this:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Jonny's was indeed faster but Scott's more concise

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 has the Counter class which can be used for this:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
list2 = ['green', 'purple', 'red', 'yellow', 'red']
set_list1 = set(list1)
list2_in_list1 = [x for x in list2 if x in set_list1]
count = Counter(list2_in_list1)
print count
# gives: Counter({'red': 2, 'yellow': 1})
```

The conversion of list1 to a set is for performance reasons (checking for an item in a set is faster than checking in a list); you could skip it for short lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count statement available with list.

```
list1 = ['red','blue', 'yellow']
list2 = ['green','purple','red','yellow','purple', 'red']
for color in list1:
    count = list2.count(color)
    print [color, count],
```

This prints out the following:

['red', 2] ['blue', 0] ['yellow', 1]